# Why did these comments get deleted? Someone else wrote the same afterward and got over 20 upvotes

Tags: discussion, comments

I asked this question: [How can I check the version of Google Chrome without it upgrading itself without asking me?](https://superuser.com/q/1123258/116475)

Someone added a comment saying "why not unplug cable?" (perhaps worded differently, I don't have access to this comment anymore…), I replied to it, then some mods deleted the two comments (his/her question and  my answer). Within the next few hours, someone else asked the same question in the comments and got 20 upvotes, which seems to show that the comment was interesting. Why did it get removed in the first place?

Answer (score 4):

Comments are transient. Comments are also a bit too much trouble to *actively police* unless someone brought it up, and when we do, we often look through and either prune, chatify or clear out the comments.

Someone flagged comments there. Comments were cleared out. Someone else commented. No one flagged it. Comments stayed.

And while potentially silly, if it mattered posting that as an *answer* explaining why it would be a great idea would have been the right thing to do anyway.

Comment: I think I'll just write some extension to hide all comments on Stack Exchange and forget about them.

Comment: Would it be possible to add those comments to the question? Without that only the OP and moderators (or users with high enough rep) can understand the question.

Comment: @MátéJuhász I do not have access to the deleted comments. I believe only mods do. (+10k users may see deleted questions and answers but not deleted comments)

Comment: Frank,  I know,  I've asked it from @JourneymanGeek, he's a moderator.